# CrashLoopBackOff Error When Trying To Create MySQL Deployment With Minikube

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm new to Kubernetes. I am trying to create a MySQL pod using a deployment .yaml file on Minikube. But I keep getting CrashLoopBackOff error.

I intent to use this pod as the database for my Flask app, the pod of which is already running.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-root-password: bXlzcWw=
```

**persistant-volume.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: manual
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

**persistant-volume-claim.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
  labels:
    app: mysql-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "1500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: mysql-root-password
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-persistant-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistant-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pvc
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
  labels:
    app: mysql-db
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql-db
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
  type: LoadBalancer
```

When I run the `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>` command, I get the following -

```
Name:             mysql-deployment-744d6df885-lm2nw
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Wed, 26 Oct 2022 22:36:27 +0600
Labels:           app=mysql-db
                  pod-template-hash=744d6df885
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               172.17.0.4
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mysql-deployment-744d6df885
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:   docker://d7ccb5efac0051851a54eb8bc8147be2271f213136fe2a20460243d0e4674035
    Image:          mysql:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:06314a7a220f6043436cfd72fd9c7f174fd58ef69fe4b788625fa53be4ab66aa
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 26 Oct 2022 22:37:13 +0600
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 26 Oct 2022 22:36:44 +0600
      Finished:     Wed, 26 Oct 2022 22:36:46 +0600
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  3
    Limits:
      cpu:     1500m
      memory:  512Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     1500m
      memory:  512Mi
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mysql-root-password' in secret 'mysql-secret'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from mysql-persistant-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-h44lh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mysql-persistant-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mysql-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-h44lh:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  47s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mysql-deployment-744d6df885-lm2nw to minikube
  Warning  BackOff    15s (x4 over 43s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulled     2s (x4 over 47s)   kubelet            Container image "mysql:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2s (x4 over 47s)   kubelet            Created container mysql
  Normal   Started    2s (x4 over 47s)   kubelet            Started container mysql
```

*Logs*

```
2022-10-26 17:22:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.31-1.el8 started.
2022-10-26 17:22:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-10-26 17:22:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.31-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-10-26T17:22:14.726596Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-10-26T17:22:14.727697Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
2022-10-26T17:22:14.732426Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-26T17:22:14.761436Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-10-26T17:22:15.248917Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-10-26T17:22:15.249090Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-10-26T17:22:15.249122Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-10-26T17:22:15.249437Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: I've literally copied and pasted your definitions in one deployment.yaml file and is up and running perfectly. Could you please paste the pod logs so we can have more info about the error that you are getting?

Comment: The `CrashLoopBackOff` tells that your container keeps crashing, so there must be something wrong on this side. Checking the logs of the container (& previous) might point you to the issue. Use `kubectl logs <podname>` or `kubectl logs <podname> --previous` to get the logs

Comment: @mauricubo I have updated the post with the pod's logs.

Comment: @chresse I have updated the post with the pod's logs

Comment: Delete the whole deployment, including the PVC an PV. Somehow your database got corrupted.

Comment: Seems that you are creating the mysql on a directory that already have data from another deployment. Delete the PVC and PV like Manuel suggested or create a new one dedicated for this deployment.

Comment: @mauricubo Tried that. Still not working. The image is being pulled locally as I have the mysql image pulled on my system. I use that for running the project using docker-compose. Could that be a reason for why the logs are showing that there is already data on that directory?

Comment: do you think that you are running the same mysql image that you used with docker-compose? I don't think that is the main reason. But, try to use another folder on your PV (like /mnt/data2) and try again. Be sure that you delete all your previous deployment. And if doesn´t work then try to delete the mysql image that is cached on your pc (to confirm what are you saying)

Comment: @neha  have you cleaned up /mnt/data on your machine? This is the path that gets mounted to the pod as host path and may have the corrupt files.

Comment: Have the same error. At first everything was running perfectly but I turned off my PC with running pod. Later on turning it on I get this `CrashLoopBackOff` error. Tried everything what you did but it didn't help. Have you found the solution?